# How will PowerApps using Dataverse as a data source and environment variables be linked?

Tags: powerapps, dataverse

I need to export my powerapps app from a dev env to another dev env.
The problem is, I couldn't figure out how to link app and env variables which I already made in the same solution.

When I used Sharepoint List as a data source of my app, I heard that the variable and app must be linked in app dev screen, and learned how.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/environmentvariables

I was expecting the same method regardless of the type of the datasource, but the powerapps dev screen with Dataverse didn't give me a same one as the case of Sharepoint List.
I would like to learn how to assign an existing environment variable of Dataverse as a datasource to powerapps.